# Fetch data from two tables using spark sql based on run date

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My application(scala/spark 2.4) reads last 6 months data from a table in hdfs(Table1) . This data will be available in a different table(Table 2) from next month. Since my application uses last 6 months of data, the source has to be both table for the first couple of months and once the new table (Table 2) has 6 months worth of data, the source should be the new table.

If the new table(Table 2) has 1 month of data, then  the program should take 1 month of data from Table 2 and 5 months prior to that from Table 1.
Similarly, when the new table(Table 2) has 2 months of data, then the program should take  2 months of data from Table 2 and prior 4 months data from Table 1.
Once the new table(Table 2) has 6 months worth of data, it shouldn't take any data from the old table(Table 1)

.
How can this be achieved?

I am a  beginner in spark and haven't been able to come up with a solution yet.

Comment: Schema for both tables is the same? If yes, it should be ease to merge them with union

Comment: Schema is different for both the tables. The newer table has more fields .

Comment: ok, you still can do the union, If you are using Spark 3.1+ you can use argument allowMissingColumns to fill missing values with nulls: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName.html If you are working on older Spark you can do it manualy (just add missing column to first df using withColumn)

Comment: Or, you can define a VIEW on top of UNION of both tables, and query this view from Spark as if it were one table.